Can you create source maps with webpack after the fact?
We ship our product with source maps created via devtool: 'nosources-source-map'.  Now, a customer is having an issue with an old release and it would be useful if we could give them a complete source map, which we don't actually have and would need to create.
I checked out the branch that was used to build that release, and changed the devtool configuration to use source-map.  The code I need to debug is in the main chunk so I updated the output.filename to match the name in the original build so that the name of the file will match the source map annotation at the bottom of the existing file.
When I replaced the original source map with the new version, it loaded fine.  However, when I tried setting breakpoints, it became clear that the new source map did not match the installed code.
Since I used the exact same branch, including the package.json, and ran npm install before building, I would have expected the new source map to match the old code.  Is that a valid expectation?  Is there some other way I could create the source map?
